# Generic overload resolution

Tags: c#, generics, overloading

I have the following scenario:

```
class Foo { }

class Foo<T> : Foo { }
```

And then two methods

```
void DoStuff(Foo foo) 
{
     DoStuffImpl(foo);
}

void DoStuffImpl(Foo foo) 
{ 
     Console.WriteLine("A");
}    
void DoStuffImpl<T>(Foo<T> foo) 
{ 
     Console.WriteLine("B");
} 

void Main() 
{
     DoStuff(new Foo<int>()); // prints A
}
```

(note, the code was written in the browser, but describes the situation I'm facing)

How can I get it to call the generic method, and print B?

Can this be done at all without reflection? I have some ideas on how it could be done with reflection, but I'm looking for a cleaner solution if one exists.

*Note: I can't make `DoStuff` generic because this will be used with WCF and open generic types are not allowed.*

Comment: Method resolution happens at compile-time, not runtime.  Once you get into the body of DoStuff, there's no way for the compiler to know that it was originally a Foo<T>.

Comment: Where is T declared in the second overload of DoStuffImpl?

Comment: @Eric, it was supposed to be DoStuffImpl<T>(Foo<T> foo), my bad.

Comment: On a side note, if operating on a `Foo<T>` yields significantly different results than operating on a `Foo`, you may have a violation of transparency.  `DoStuff(Foo)` should be able to operate on any kind of `Foo`, which means all classes that derive from `Foo` should perform according to the specified behaviors of `Foo` that DoStuff(foo) relies on.  You're essentially trying to provide a polymorphic behavior for the `DoStuff` method outside the implementation of `Foo` and `Foo<T>`.  You may want to reconsider the separation of responsibilities that led to this problem.

Comment: @Dan: This is supposed to just be a workaround for WCF's inability to use generic parameters. I actually wanted to have two separate versions of the DoStuff method, one generic, and one not, but WCF doesn't let you have open generic type parameters for operation contracts. So, with this method I can trick it into accepting Foo<T>.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

(I assume you already understand why this is happening. If not, read my [overload resolution article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx) and let me know if it's still unclear.)

If you're using C# 4 you *could* use dynamic typing:

```
void DoStuff(Foo foo) 
{
    dynamic d = foo;
    DoStuffImpl(d);
}
```

Note how this doesn't just have a dynamic parameter - the idea is that by restricting `foo` to be of type `Foo` or a subclass, we'll *always* have a valid `DoStuffImpl` to call... it's just that the best method will be determined at execution time, not compile time.

If you're stuck in pre-C# 4, you could potentially do it with double dispatch:

```
class Foo
{
    public virtual void CallStuffImpl(FooImplType x)
    {
        x.DoStuffImpl(this);
    }
}

class Foo<T> : Foo
{
    public override void CallStuffImpl(FooImplType x)
    {
        // Looks like it's redundant, but isn't! "this" is
        // known to be Foo<T> rather than Foo
        x.DoStuffImpl(this);
    }
}
```

Then:

```
void DoStuff(Foo foo) 
{
    foo.CallStuffImpl(this); // Let it dispatch appropriately
}
```

Comment: +1, Cool, had no idea dynamic could be used for overload resolution.

Comment: Thanks Jon. Yes, I understand why it's happening. Not using C# 4.0 yet, but this would be a good reason to switch to it if this would work!

Answer (score 17):

Overload resolution is performed at *compile time*. When "DoStuff" is compiled, it has already decided which version of DoStuffImpl to call, and it decides that based on the information available at compile time, not the information available at runtime.

There are four kinds of method dispatching in C#:

- static dispatching chooses a static method at compile time. At runtime, the chosen method is called.
- instance dispatching chooses an instance method at compile time. At runtime, the chosen method is called.  (This is the form of dispatching used on non-virtual instance methods and on virtual methods called with "base.")
- virtual dispatching chooses an instance method at compile time. At runtime, the *most overridding version of that method on the runtime type of the object* is called.
- dynamic dispatching does nothing at compile time (*). At runtime *the compiler starts up again and does the compile-time analysis at runtime, and generates fresh new code that is what would have been written had you gotten it right at compile time in the first place.*  This is every bit as expensive as it sounds; fortunately the result is cached so that on the second call, you don't get all the cost of analysis and codegen again.

Dynamic dispatching is only available in C# 4, or any version of VB.

(*) This is not quite true; there are some circumstances in which the compiler can do analysis at compile time even if the arguments to the method are dynamic. The details are complicated.

Comment: Thanks Eric, looks like it's time for us to move on to C# 4.0/VS2010, dynamic dispatch seems like the cleanest solution.

Comment: Quote: "the compiler starts up again".  That's just a figure of speech for what the DLR does, right?

Comment: @Hans: It's not the DLR per se; it's the C# binder implementing a DLR interface. (In particular I don't believe it's available on dlr.codeplex.com.)

Comment: <quote>The details are complicated</quote>  Do I smell a blog post, or maybe an entire series?

Comment: @Hans: OK, *a* compiler starts up again. The C# runtime binder is a port of the relevant code from the command-line compiler libraries.

Comment: @Ben: See Chris Burrows's blog for the series.