# Is there any priority when resolving method overloads?

Tags: c#, generics, overloading

Why does execute `TestMethod<T>(params T[] input)` method instead of execute `TestMethod(object input)`.I am confusing why complier execute generic method.Is there any priority hierarchy on .net framework ?

```
class TestClass
{
    static void Main()
    {
        TestMethod("Hello World");
    }

    static void TestMethod(object input)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("object");
    }

    static void TestMethod<T>(params T[] input)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("params T[]");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, there's a mechanism for [overload resolution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691336(v=vs.71).aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comment on your question contains the link to the overload resolution specs of C# which contains all infos you need to answer the question in depth. It's not the most easy read, though and hard to find the actual path of resolution in your case, so here is what happens, as far as I can tell:

**Parameter arrays:**

First, we need to look at what the `params` keyword does: As it is a shortcut for the developers convenience, here is what it is identical to:

```
static void TestMethod<T>(params T[] input)
```

gets translated to

```
static void TestMethod<T>(T[] item)
```

and calls get translated accordingly:

```
TestMethod("string2", "string2");
```

gets translated to:

```
TestMethod(new string[] { "string1", "string2" );
```

**Resolution:**

With this in mind, let's see what the compiler does: The compiler evaluates its options to resolve your call at runtime.

Your call is:

```
TestMethod("string");
```

The first option is to translate this call to:

```
TestMethod(new string[] { "string" });
```

This would allow to call the generic version, while using `string` as `T`, which would result in the 'resolved method signature':

```
TestMethod(string[] item)
```

So, the required conversion from actual to required argument type is

```
string[] to string[]
```

Option b is to interpret the parameter `"string"` as what it is in our eyes, as a `string`. Then it would be feasible to call the non-generic version.

```
string to object
```

The conversions are evaluated according to section 7.4.3.4 of the C# spec and to avoid the *downgrading* of string to object, the first option is chosen.

Answer (score 5):

this is because of overload resolution.

here is a good [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tb18a48w.aspx)

Similar Question:
[Generic Overload Resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678703/generic-overload-resolution)

[image]

Comment: +1 for the nice image, -1 because it does not help for the specific case in question (at least not without additional information on how param[] fits in there).