# C# overload resolution with generics

Tags: c#

I come from a C++ background and I am relatively new to C#. 
Currently, I am trying to write two print functions, the first of which accepts a generic array parameter (and prints the items of the array to the command line) and a second one which accepts a generic primitive parameter (and invokes its `ToString()` method). Here's my code:

```
using System;

namespace OverloadResolution
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string[] foo = new string[] { "A", "B", "C" };
      Extensions.PrintMe(foo);
      Extensions.PrintMe("Hello world");
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }

  public static class Extensions
  {
    public static void PrintMe<T>(T[] elm)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("PrintMe<T>(T[] elm)");
      Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", elm));
    }

    public static void PrintMe<T>(T elm)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("PrintMe<T>(T elm)");
      Console.WriteLine(elm.ToString());
    }
  }
}
```

Everything works as expected and the correct overloads are chosen. However, if I change my code as follows:

```
using System;

namespace OverloadResolution
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string[] foo = new string[] { "A", "B", "C" };
      Extensions.PrintMe2(foo); // <<< Note the PrintMe2 function
      Extensions.PrintMe2("Hello world"); // <<< Note the PrintMe2 function
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }

  public static class Extensions
  {
    public static void PrintMe2<T>(T elm)
    {
      PrintMe(elm);
    }

    public static void PrintMe<T>(T[] elm)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("PrintMe<T>(T[] elm)");
      Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", elm));
    }

    public static void PrintMe<T>(T elm)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("PrintMe<T>(T elm)");
      Console.WriteLine(elm.ToString());
    }
  }
}
```

the type information seems to get lost when calling the `PrintMe2` function because, internally, the second `PrintMe` function is invoked in both cases. Are there any special rules which apply in this case? Or am I missing something? I use C#7.0 and .NET framework 4.7. I should note that I already learned that the use of C# generics is quite limited as compared to C++ templates...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generic overload resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678703/generic-overload-resolution)

Comment: @DragandDrop: It's not quite a duplicate of that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When `PrintMe2` is being compiled, we have to perform overload resolution to determine which `PrintMe` method is being called, and we have to emit the correct method token into `PrintMe2`s IL to identify that method.

At the point at which `PrintMe2` is being compiled, we do not know the nature of its `T` type parameter. It could be anything. The only version of `PrintMe` that is similarly unrestricted is `PrintMe<T>(T elm)`. Therefore, we emit the method token for that specific method into our IL.

Generics are *different* to templates, most notably because they *are* compiled separately from any code that may make use of them. We have to make decisions at *their* compile time, and those decisions have to be valid for all possible type parameters (subject to any type constraints applied to the class/method in which the type parameter(s) are declared)

If you want a method in which overload resolution only takes place based on the *runtime* type of the passed in parameter, you can use `dynamic`, but that's quite ugly and brings in lots of overheads. It may also lead to runtime errors in no *specific* overload is most specific for some use cases.

Comment: Thanks for this good explanation - especially for pointing out the difference to templates.

Comment: @Marcel - yes, I think it's quite instructive to look at templates in C++ and generics in both Java and .NET to see how the same basic concept can be expressed and implemented in very different ways. They lead to different trade-offs. .NET, of course, was aiming for cross-language support for generics and so could not make the same decisions as were made for C++.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the argument to pseudo-type `dynamic` to force C# compiler to select the most specific overload based on the actual value of the argument, like this:

```
PrintMe((dynamic)elm);
```

However, if you inspect the generated IL code, this comes with a runtime penalty, so you should use the `dynamic` keyword sparingly.